# How to keep background color changes on page reload?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table which contain cells that when clicked, will change the cell's background color to green. When I reload the page, however, the background color reverts back to its original color; white. Is there any way I can prevent it from reverting? To just keep it green after I clicked it?

JS:

```
        function eight(){
            var eight = document.getElementById("eight");
            eight.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        }
```

HTML:

```
        <td id="eight" onclick="eight(); ">
            <a>8</a>
            <br>
            <center>-</center>
            <br>
            <center>-</center>
            <hr>
            <center>-</center>
            <br>
            <center>-</center>
        </td>
```

*Ignore the content inside the `<td>` tags.

Comment: You can have a boolean isLoaded and store it in local storage. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: `localStorage`, `sessionStorage` and `document.cookie` are your choices in JavaScript. `document.cookie` works on all Browsers. I recommend using a Library if using `document.cookie`, due to Client Side (Browser) limitations. If you are using HTML5 stuff you're fine with `localStorage` and `sessionStorage`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to store the color value in **Client side Cookie** or **Server Side Session**. Modern browsers supports **localStorage** also..

Try this Code..

```
function changeBackground() {
        if (sessionStorage.getItem('colour')) {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = sessionStorage.getItem('colour');
        }else{
            document.body.style.backgroundColor =  "#BB0A21";
            sessionStorage.setItem('colour', "#BB0A21");
        }
    }

  // then you'll need to call your function on page load
  changeBackground();
```

Comment: *Modern browsers support `localStorage` also.* No, **all** browsers support `localStorage` (unless you're living in 2009).

Comment: @user663031 This gives this error in my case
Uncaught ReferenceError: backclr is not defined when function is called on top

Answer (score 1):

As @Yasin says

use localstorage.take global variable

first add a class to all the cells

suppose color.then

```
 var cells=document.getElementsByClassname('color');
        var colours=[];
        if(localstorage.getItem('colours'))
        {
        colours = JSON.parse(localstorage.getItem('colours'));  // if alreay there 

        for(i=0;i<cells.length;i++)
        {
           for(j=0;j<colours.length;j++)
             {
                if(cells[i].getAttribute('id')==colours[j].id)
                {
                   cells[i].style.backgroundColor = colours[j].colour;
                 }
               }
        }


        }

        function eight(){
                    var eight = document.getElementById("eight");


                eight.style.backgroundColor = "green";
                 colours.push({id:'eight',colour:'green'});
                 localstorage.setItem('colours',JSON.stringify(colours));


   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried a way to achieve the request you provided,sessionStorage should be the best solution for you,cookie can do it anyway,but html5 supports Web Storage,here are my demo about that.

```html
<html DOCTYPE>
<head>
<title>hello world</title>
</head>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
#t1{
 background-color: aliceblue;
}
</style>
<table id="t1" onclick="eight();">
<tr>
<td>hello world</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>hello world</td></tr>
<tr><td>hello world</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
 var t = document.getElementById("t1");
 window.addEventListener("load", function(){
  var color = window.sessionStorage.getItem("tableColor");
  if(color == 'undefined'){
   t.style.backgroundColor = "aliceblue";
  }else if(color == "green"){
   t.style.backgroundColor = color;
  }else{
   alert("another color you have chosen");
  }
 }, false);
})()
function eight(){
 var eight = document.getElementById("t1");
 eight.style.backgroundColor = "green";
 window.sessionStorage.setItem("tableColor", "green");
}
</script>
</html>
```

and it will ok after you click the table and reload the page.the color will remain the previous status and only if you close your browser and reopen this page again, the table background will change to the origin status.