# It's possible the element in html page's status don't change when I refreshed？

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

for example, I clicked a button, then the `<body>` add a element like a `<p>` (maybe more changes), now if I clicked F5, the page will back to the status which is no the `<p>`.

Is there a way to keep the `<p>`?

sorry about that my english is poor.

Comment: you can keep this info in localStorage

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38928990/8206432) on how to keep JavaScript changes after a page reload useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the Javascript LocalStorage API or use a statut code in the url like

http://example.com/yourpage.html?code=1

with php you can use this :

```
    <?php
        $statut = $_GET['code'];
        if($statut === 1){
          $message = 'Your text here';
        }
        else{
          $message = 'another message';
        }
    ?>
```